# ROR how to send it via email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, send

I have html page like this

```
    <b> <p>Adres:<br><a href="http://www.<%= domainpost.content %>" target="_blank"><%= domainpost.content %></a></p></b>
<b> <p>Seller:<br><a href="/users/<%= domainpost.user_id %>"><%= domainpost.user_id %> <%= @users
 %></a></p></b>
<p>Date:<br><%= domainpost.registerdate %></p>

           </div>
              <div class="span3">
              <p>Additional:<br><%= domainpost.additiona %></p>

            <p>Expire date:<br><%= domainpost.expiredate %></p>

           </div>
    </div>


<div class="clearfix">
            <label for="name">
              Additional info:
            </label>
            <div class="input">
              <input type="text" name="infoforseller" id="infoforseller" value="" class="span6 required" role="input" aria-required="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```

What i must do to send it via email to <%= domainpost.user_id %> 
i have actionmailer and its work with after register email

what i must change in this code? what do in controler?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this..well explained and documented.[Sending mails using rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Create a mailer

```
  $ rails generate mailer UserMailer
```

Call this mailer from action in controller, add a method to mailer and create a mailer view with the same name as method. You can push the view code in this mailer view and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to sending emails in Rails at http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email.